# What's the derivative of $f(x)^{g(x)}$?

Tags: calculus

Yo lo calculé con Wolfram Alpha, pero no entendí muy bien cómo hacerlos. Gracias por las recomendaciones.

---

I calculated it using Wolfram Alpha, but I didn't understand very well how to do them. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: My answer here may be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/164810/409

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align}
y&=f(x)^{g(x)}\\
\ln y&=g(x)\ln f(x)\\
\dfrac{dy}{dx}\dfrac{1}{y}&=g'(x)\ln f(x)+g(x)\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\\
\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=y[g'(x)\ln f(x)+g(x)\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}]\\ 
\dfrac{dy}{dx}&=f(x)^{g(x)}\left[g'(x)\ln f(x)+g(x)\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\right]\\ 
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

$$
\begin{align}
\def\d{\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}}
\d\left(f(x)^{g(x)}\right)
&=
\d\left(\left(\mathrm e^{\log f(x)}\right)^{g(x)}\right)
\\
&=
\d\left(\mathrm e^{g(x)\log f(x)}\right)
\\
&=
\mathrm e^{g(x)\log f(x)}\d(g(x)\log f(x))
\\
&=
f(x)^{g(x)}\left(g'(x)\log f(x)+\frac{g(x)f'(x)}{f(x)}\right)\;.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Regla de la cadena (chain rule):

Con una constante $k$ (with a constant $k$):

$$(1)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\left(f(x)^k\right)'=kf(x)^{k-1}\,f'(x)$$
$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;k>0\Longrightarrow\left(k^{g(x)}\right)'=k^{g(x)}\log k\cdot g'(x)$$